# Why is ORDER only returning first row

Tags: r

I have a fairly simple data.frame (`fract_data`) that I'm trying to sort and yet when I apply the `ORDER` function only the first row is returned. Shouldn't all the rows be returned? How should I be using `ORDER` to return all the rows?

```
    fract_data[order("date"),]
        date code rank.ey rank.roce rank.combined rank.final fract
1 2005-01-31  ABC       1         8             9          4     3
```

As shown below there are 48 rows in `fract_data`

```
attributes(fract_data)
$names
[1] "date"          "code"          "rank.ey"       "rank.roce"     "rank.combined" "rank.final"    "fract"        

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$row.names
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41
[42] 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
```

It also doesn't appear to be a print or display issue given the attributes returned below where `fract_data2` has only 1 row.

```
> fract_data2 <- fract_data[order("date"),]
> attributes(fract_data2)
$names
[1] "date"          "code"          "rank.ey"       "rank.roce"     "rank.combined" "rank.final"    "fract"        

$row.names
[1] 1

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`order()` expects one or more vectors, and you feed it a character vector containing only one element, "date". Try `fract_data[order(fract_data$date), ]` instead.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, I thought it would be something simple. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: try also `arrange(fract_data, date)` in package `plyr`